# Mapping a local domain to http://localhost:<port_number>

Tags: dns, iptables, redirection, hosts

I have a `/etc/hosts` file with the two following lines:

```
127.0.0.2   myapp.dev
127.0.0.3   api.myapp.dev
```

and this works fine. When I ping `myapp.dev` it maps to `127.0.0.2` and when I ping `api.myapp.dev` it maps to `127.0.0.3`, as it should be.

Now I need to map `127.0.0.2` to `127.0.0.1:3000` and `127.0.0.3` to `127.0.0.1:3001`.

This is necessary because I am trying to run a Rack application whose configuration file `config.ru` is

```
#\ -w -p 3001

require 'emeraldfw'

ENVIRONMENT = ENV['EMERALD_ENV'].nil? ? :development : ENV['EMERALD_ENV']

use Rack::Reloader, 0
use Rack::ContentLength

if (ENVIRONMENT == :production) then
  use Rack::Static, :urls => {"/" => 'index.html'}, :root => 'fe/build'
else
  Dir.chdir('fe')
  spawn 'npm start'
  Dir.chdir('..')
end
run EmeraldFW::Loader.new
```

What this config file does is running the Rack application at port 3001. When the environment variable EMERALD_END is set to `production` it uses `Rack::Static` to serve the static files. On the other hand, when EMERALD_ENV is set to `development` or `test` it starts a ReactJS application as the front-end application at port 3000.

The general idea now is accessing the front-end application at `http://myapp.dev` and accessing the API (back-end) at `http://api.myapp.dev`.

I tried some hacks and even considered the possibility of using **iptables** or other packet filtering software to do this. I know that I may use **iptables** rules to redirect input from a certain IP/Port to another IP, but I'd rather find an easier solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is virtual hosting an option?

Comment: Using a server like Apache or Nginx, @JeremiahMegel?

Comment: I was thinking with the Rack application itself, but using Apache/Nginx/Caddy as a reverse proxy with virtual hosts might also work.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with the React application itself. This would be the best option, because this software I am creating would have a very complicated installation process if I had to add the installation/configuration of a web server or reverse proxy to it.